# How to get coordinates of point where drawing arc ended in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

Please consider [this](http://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/rraapJ?editors=1010) example.

How can I get coordinates of point where arc ended? Is there any function for this?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

var context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.arc(115, 115, 100, (Math.PI/2)+Math.PI, 0, false);
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic trigonometry gives us formula

```
 X_End = X_Center + R * Cos(End_Angle)
 Y_End = Y_Center + R * Sin(End_Angle)
```

for you case

```
 X_End = 115 + 100 * Cos(0) = 215
```

and find `Y_End` yourself